# update variable on @Input() change

Tags: angular

I have an Input variable whose value is changed in parentComponent.
On every change, I need to update a variable called `currentNumber` local to child component. At the moment I only initialise it in `onInit` method, but input changes over the life time of childComponent.ts

```
ChildComponent.ts

@Input() input;
...
...
ngOnInit(){
    this.currentNumber = this.data.someOtherNumber+this.input.numberIneed;;
}
```

I am aware of observers, but I feel like that declaring another service just for this is an overkill.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a setter :

```
private _input: number;
@Input() set input(value: number) {
     this._input = value;
     this.currentNumber = this.data.someOtherNumber + this.input.numberIneed; 
}; 
get input() { return this._input; }
```

or ngOnChanges :

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
    // ...
    ngOnChanges(changes: { [propName: string]: SimpleChange }) {
         if (changes['input'] && changes['input'].currentValue !== changes['input'].previousValue) {
             this.currentNumber = this.data.someOtherNumber+this.input.numberIneed;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a setter.

```
@Input('input')
set input(value: numer) {
    this.currentNumber = this.data.someOtherNumber+this.input.numberIneed;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ngOnChanges. If input changes this function is called:

```
ngOnChanges(){
  this.currentNumber = this.data.someOtherNumber + this.input.numberIneed;
}
```